# JSF ui:repeat | Just display the first 5 elements of a List

Tags: jsf, uirepeat

Hi can someone tell me if its possible to just render the first 5 elements of a list with ui:repeat without creating a seperate List for this?

I googled but couldn't find something about this.

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `end` attribute for that. From the documentation:

> If value specified: Iteration ends at the item located at the specified index (inclusive). If value not specified: Iteration ends when index reaches the specified value (inclusive).

Note that there also is a `begin` attribute. Documentation:

> If value specified: Iteration begins at the item located at the specified index. First item of the collection has index 0. If value not specified: Iteration begins with index set at the specified value.

So you can simply do:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.myCollection}" end="4" ...>
  ...
</ui:repeat>
```